# Where does the "err" argument come from in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Not sure whether this is more a general JS question than Mongoose per se, but what is the function that provides the "err" argument in the code below?

```js
//Save a new cat called "Thomas" to the "Cats" collection

Thomas.save( function(err, cat) {
    if (err){
        console.log("Cat not saved")
    } else {
        console.log("Saved")
    }
})
```

Comment: Probably the `.save` function?

Comment: You'd need to go poking into the Mongoose source code to find it. (It also **doesn't matter** unless you are trying to edit the Mongoose library itself. The documentation tells you what the function you've written should expect to receive as arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ever Asynchronous operation u are performing `save()` or `findByName()` ..etc, when u use callback, Traditionally the first parameter of the `callback` is the `error` value. If the function hits an `error`, then they typically call the `callback` with the first parameter being an `Error` object.

If it cleanly exits, then they will call the `callback` with the first parameter being null and the rest being the return value(s).

```
asyncOperation ( params.., function ( err, returnValues.. ) {
   //This code gets run after the async operation gets run
});
```

In your case `.save()` gives err if hits an `error`.